# How to set two components vertically in one JPanel with fixed size upper component?

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager

Here are the requirements in detail:

- one fixed sized image on the top in a `JPanel`
- depending on the different input, a hint `JLabel` shows or hides below the image
- the panel should have the same size as the image when there is no hint label showing

Here is the sample code:

```
   JFrame frame = new JFrame();
   frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
   Container panel = frame.getContentPane();
   BorderLayout boxLayout = new BorderLayout();
   panel.setLayout(boxLayout);
   JLabel fixedLabel = new JLabel("fixed");
   fixedLabel.setBackground(Color.green);
   fixedLabel.setOpaque(true);
   fixedLabel.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(600, 120));
   fixedLabel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(600, 120));
   fixedLabel.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(600, 120));
   panel.add(fixedLabel, BorderLayout.NORTH);

   JLabel lbl = new JLabel("can be hidden");
   fixedLabel.addMouseListener(new MouseListener() {
       boolean showButton = false;
       @Override
       public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {

       }

       @Override
       public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
           if (!showButton) {
               showButton = true;
               panel.add(lbl, BorderLayout.CENTER);
               panel.revalidate();
               panel.repaint();
           } else {
               showButton = false;
               panel.remove(lbl);
               panel.revalidate();
               panel.repaint();
           }

       }

       @Override
       public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {

       }

       @Override
       public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {

       }

       @Override
       public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {

       }
   });

   frame.pack();
   frame.setVisible(true);
```

when the first time clicked, the panel won't automatically enlarge vertically. after manually enlarged, click again and the panel won't automatically shrink to the top label size

Please guide me on how to proceed.

Comment: The borderlayout approach should work. But instead of hiding the label, set its text to a single space.

Comment: How do you create the image? Is it a `BufferedImage`? Is it an `ImageIcon`? You wrote in your question: _Here is what I tried_ Can you [edit] your question and post what you tried? Please try to post your code as a [mcve].

Comment: You need to define what should fill the empty space when the `JLabel` is hidden ? It can not be empty.  A blank component ? or the image ?

Comment: *BorderLayout with imaged in NORTH and label in CENTER: *  it should be the image in CENTER and the label in the PAGE_END. The size of the CENTER component is adjusted as more or less space is available.

Comment: @c0der JPanel has the same size with fixed image when JLabel hidden

Comment: @camickr the image should have fixed size

Comment: But you stated the panel must have the same size. How is that possible if you add the label to the panel? Either the image has to shrink or the panel has to grow. Or the entire frame has to grow/shrink which is not a good UI. You requirement is not clear.

Comment: @camickr *"You requirement is not clear."* I agree. OTOH - leftfield suggestion, ***maybe*** (1) the op's users would be better served by providing a [`JToolTip`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/JToolTip.html). OP: A tooltip can hover in front of elements of the GUI, and therefore would not affect the component layout of the main GUI at all. 1) In this case 'maybe' is doing some heavy lifting, as I'm entirely unclear how the OP expects the end result to appear.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out with below code

```
panel.addContainerListener(new ContainerListener() {
      @Override
      public void componentAdded(ContainerEvent e) {
          System.out.println("added");
          System.out.println(panel.getBounds());
          Rectangle bounds = frame.getBounds();
          bounds.height +=38;
          frame.setBounds(bounds);
          frame.revalidate();
          frame.repaint();
          System.out.println(frame.getBounds());
      }

      @Override
      public void componentRemoved(ContainerEvent e) {
          System.out.println("removed");
          System.out.println(panel.getBounds());
          Rectangle bounds = frame.getBounds();
          bounds.height -= 38;
          frame.setBounds(bounds);
          frame.revalidate();
          frame.repaint();
          System.out.println(frame.getBounds());
      }
  });
```